# Real solution of Trigonometric and inverse Trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

> The number of real solution of

> the  $\displaystyle \sin^{-1}(|\cos(x)|)=\cos^{-1}(|\sin(x)|)$

> in $[0,4\pi]$ is

What I have done as

using $\displaystyle \sin^{-1}(x)+\cos^{-1}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Then $\displaystyle \sin^{-1}(|\cos(x)|)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin^{-1}(|\sin(x)|)$

$\displaystyle \sin^{-1}(|\sin(x)|)+\sin^{-1}(|\cos(x)|)=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Now I did not know how do i go ahead

Please look on that problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the $\sin$ of both sides:
$$|\cos x|=\sin(\cos^{-1}(|\sin x|))$$
Drawing a triangle for $\theta=\cos^{-1}(|\sin x|)$, you will get that adjacent is $|\sin x|$ and hypotenuse is $1$, so opposite is $\sqrt{1-(|\sin x|)^2}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$. So the RHS becomes: $$\sin(\cos^{-1}(|\sin x|))=\sin\theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}/1=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$$ But due to the famous trigonometric identity $$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$$
You will find that $\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}=|\cos x|$. This is the exact same thing as the LHS!!!

This indicates that there are infinitely many real solutions in the interval $[0,4\pi]$. In fact, for any $x$ you plug in, both sides of the equation will always be equal to each other!

You can even verify this by graphing $y=\sin^{-1}(|\cos x|)$ and $y=\cos^{-1}(|\sin x|)$ on the same graph in your favorite graphing calculator, and see that they intersect exactly on top of each other!

Comment: Yep... Correct.  ($+1$)

Answer (score 2):

Following your way only:

$$\dfrac\pi2=\cos^{-1}|\sin x|+\cos^{-1}|\cos x|$$

As $0\le|\sin x|,|\cos x|\le1,$

$$S=\cos^{-1}|\sin x|+\cos^{-1}|\cos x|=\cos^{-1}(|\sin x\cos x|-\sqrt{(1-\cos^2x)(1-\sin^2x)})$$

As for real $a,\sqrt{a^2}=|a|,$

$$S=\cos^{-1}(|\sin x\cos x|-|\sin x\cos x|)=?$$